# Dynamically assigns different value for the environment variable upon a Docker service scale

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

For some situation, we might need to scale up the service and assign the different value for the environment variable, for example, NODE_ID (to be used internally).

Usually, I create a script to run my service with a dynamic parameter as preferred scale.

```
$ docker run -e NODE_ID=node_01 ...
$ docker run -e NODE_ID=node_02 ...
...
$ docker run -e NODE_ID=node_20 ...
```

**Question**
Is there any way to achieve this with the docker swarm mode, e.g.

`$ docker service create ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only value you can get it the container id by using `$(hostname)`. That gives you a unique value for each container. There is no way to provide a custom one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps me partially, at least to access a unique container id. 

But still, I'm also looking for the way to pass the other parameters to different container while scaling the service with docker swarm.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this, I need to do this too, be very interested in what you say on this one